# Want to update BIOS but have to overwrite a OEM BIOS

Tags: bios, windows-11

So I need to update my BIOS to version F51g at least in order to support my new AMD Ryzen 7 5700X, but there in lies the problem.
I purchased the mainboard in a whole PC from Wortmann in 2018 and as a result of that the BIOS seems to be OEMId locked, which prevents me from updating the BIOS as I dont have access to the serial number.
I have already found a way to go around QFlash using a flashdrive formatted using Rufus and trying to flash the F31 version using Efiflash. Sadly this way the BIOS doesnt get updated and just stays at the old F23 without throwing any errors.

Comment: Which motherboard ?

Comment: @harrymc That is the AX370MDS3H. Let me know if you need any other information

Comment: @John The BIOS came with OEM licensed software which "locks" the software into only being updatable through the third party manufacturer. In my example I purchased a whole PC from Wortmann and gradually replaced parts until I now find out that the mainboard is not able to update using consumer software.

Comment: @John As stated in the post I bought the whole PC 5/6 years ago and on top of that the purchase wasnt made by me personally because of my age back then. For Wortmann to even aknowledge that I own this PC I would need the serial number of the item purchased, which i cant provide

Comment: The latest BIOS version for this motherboard is [F51l](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-AX370M-DS3H-rev-1x/support#support-dl-bios). What happens if you try to flash it (carefully) and what is the exact error?

Comment: @harrymc As you should be able to see in the version F31 you arent able to directly flash just the newest BIOS as F31 is needed in order to use QFlash and the problem of a mismatching OEMID would still hold up

Comment: Are you getting an error when flashing with Efiflash? Have you tried contacting Gigabyte Support?

Comment: @harrymc When flashing with Efiflash the process of installing a new BIOS seems fine until after the reboot where the BIOS version just stays the same. I have sent out a ticket to the Gigabyte Support a few hours ago but dont expect a reply before next week.

Comment: If the situation is as you describe then Gigabyte won't help you, only the OEM and yes, they'll probably need to see some proof of purchase.